London's cooling center locations in GIS format
I was wondering if I could find London's cooling spaces (CS) in a GIS format (either, shp, geojson or gpkg). The CS are presented below and the map can be found here:

I've searched the website but I could't find any link to download the points. Anyone knows if such data exists in a GIS format?

I may have found some GeoJSON files inspecting network connections:

Parks with hot weather amenities
Drinking water fountains
Tier 1 cool spaces
Tier 2 cool spaces


Thank you for the effort providing the dataset. I contacted London City Hall and they gave me the points showed in the image in the question.

@Nikos: Great, happy to help. If this answered your question, I'd be happy if you accepted - after all this is Open Data SE, right?
